# Why do I have multiple branches of a similar name after setting up git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I have just created a new Git repository backed by Subversion, using git svn.

On inspection of the branches created, there are several branches with a similar name, suffixed `@{number}`:

```
$ git branch -r
tags/project-0.0.1.0
tags/project-0.0.1.0@175525
tags/project-0.0.1.0@178802
tags/project-0.0.1.0@179205
trunk
trunk@175525
trunk@179205
```

What do these mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These happen because svn tracks branches and tags as separate directories rather than with an internal representation, allowing things to happen that cannot be adequately represented in the git universe.

For example, if you rename a directory below `branches/`, you have effectively renamed the branch at this version; if you later rename it back, then git-svn can not determine that this is in fact the same branch as before, and so it creates a new branch, suffixed with the version where it found the breaking change. For tags, simply changing a file is sufficient, as git does not allow versioned tags (and, honestly, the concept does not make a lot of sense).

Comment: Actually, Git is quite happy with changing tags. Since Subversion treats tags exactly the same as branches, just stored in a different folder, Git treats Subversion tags exactly the same as it treats Subversion branches, just with the reference in `refs/remotes/tags` rather than `refs/remotes`. What Git won't handle nicely is the same tag name being used multiple times, for exactly the reason you talk about.